# Pilot the the reset line by two input

Tags: arduino-uno

I have two input signal that when activated have to restart the ardiuno board so I have to connect them to the RESET pin. As you know the arduino board have only one RESET pin so I can't connect both to the same pin.
I think that a good idea is a circuit that takes the two inputs and activate the RESTART pin when one of the two is active.
Have you any idea to solve that problem?

Thank you.

Comment: use a logic IC (OR gate) or two reset lines in parallel with appropriate resistors.

Comment: Can you tell us why? What are those signals and why do you want to reset the arduino? Such questions might be the xy-problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

Just use diode logic.

The resistor is probably not needed because the Arduino has an internal pullup resistor.

This assumes that the two reset inputs are `active low`

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZp7uj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution. (Voted)

Answer (score -1):

What you want is an AND gate (e.g., 74HC08, which contains 4 AND gates).

An AND gate is a chip which sets its output HIGH when *both* inputs to it are HIGH.

Symbolically it looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn8S2X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This, of course, is assuming that both your reset signals are *active low* - that is, they are normally in the HIGH state, but when they want to reset the board they go LOW.

You can do the same thing with three transistors.  Two transistors in series make a NAND gate (like an AND gate but the output is inverted), and a third makes a NOT gate to invert the output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWKGOo.png)</sup>

Note that R4 is optional, since the RESET pin already has a 10KΩ pullup resistor in it.